# How do I append a dollar sign to my sectionIndexTitlesForTableView?

Tags: iphone, core-data, table-index

I'm working on an app that displays entries in a Core Data table by dollar figure. I sorted my table by a dollar figure attribute. I also use that as the basis for the table index.

At first I made my titles for my table sections strings. But that didn't work. My table index would sort like this:

$10

$100

$25

$5

$50

Instead of  this:

$5

$10

$25

$50

$100

So I changed my model to make the section name attribute an integer. I populated the database, and they sort correctly:

5

10

25

50

100

Now I just have to append a dollar sign to the section index title.

I thought I would do something like this...

```
- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    NSArray *frcSectionTitlesArray = [fetchedResultsController sectionIndexTitles];

    NSString *dollarSectionName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%f", frcSectionTitlesArray];

    return dollarSectionName;

}
```

But of course that does't work because I'm dealing with an array, and not a string.

Any ideas?

Comment: It's not clear what you already tried; I think this should work.

Comment: @jtbandes, he's returning an NSString in a method that expects an NSArray, thats a pretty big clue it won't work.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    NSArray * frcSectionTitlesArray = [fetchedResultsController sectionIndexTitles];
    NSMutableArray *newTitles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] unit];
    for (NSString *title in frcSectionTitlesArray) {
        [newTitles addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%@", title]];
    }

    return [newTitles autorelease];

}
```

It goes through each title and prepends a dollar sign into a new string, and adds it to a new array, which is returned.